# Is it possible to resize NSView automatically in swift?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsview

Is it possible to make resizable custom NSView (used in Popover) i.e. for instance for the case when the width of NSView is dependent on the some calculated parameter?

More details. I can set up the fixed width of NSView in interface bilder, but this is not what I need. I have an array (available in my Controller file) and from this array I have number of elements. Each element - character - has width in X points. I need to draw the X axis and the length of X axis is the product of numbers of elements and width of the element. The X axis should be inside of NSView, so NSView should have variable size in dependence on the size of the array. The size of the array depends on the analysis of the text (during the run of the program) typed by user, so the width of NSView depends on the user. Then when user click the popover the NSView should have width defined actually by user.

**Update**

I found out that resizing can be done by:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myView: NSView!

let newSizeOfView = NSMakeSize(x, y)
myView.setFrameSize(newSizeOfView)
```

Comment: @rocky Could you write what I can use to do this ?

Comment: Can you please be more specific about how you would like to size your view?

Comment: @rocky I have an array (available in my Controller file) and from this array I have number of elements.  Each elements - character - has  width in X point., I need to draw the X axis and the length of X axis is the product of numbers of elements and width of the element. The X axis should be inside of my NSView, so NSView should have variable size in dependence on the size of the array.

Comment: OK you basically answered your own question. Just set the width of the view to be the product of the number of elements and the width of each element.

Comment: @rocky Probably I am missing simple thing, I can set up the fixed width of NSView in interface bilder, but this is not what I need. The size of the array depends on the analysis of the text  (during the run of program) typed by user, so the width of NSView depends on the user. Then when user click the popover the  NSView should have width defined actually by user.